# Is there a way to apply a clipping stencil to the 'near' clip for a camera in threejs?

Tags: three.js, 3d, clipping

I'm creating a piece of code that will allow my client to zoom into blueprints like the one below, and clip into them, essentially creating an interactive cross section. that's simple enough, by just setting the near plane to a value higher than 0, but I'd like to know if there is a way to apply the crosshatching pattern that you see below on the areas that are clipped. On top of that, is there a way to apply a border around the area that is clipped, creating an outline? [I know there is clipping in three js which uses planes](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clip#webgl_clipping_stencil), but I'd like to know if it is possible to apply a stencil to the near clipping plane for a camera, and if so, how is it done?

[image]

Comment: No, there's no way to do what you're asking. The near plane simply cuts off anything in front of it, and it doesn't know anything about the geometry it's clipping, so you wouldn't be able to draw a color on the inside. Your best bet is to go with the clipping demo you linked.

Comment: @Marquizzo that's a pity, but it was worth a shot. maybe I can parent a plane to the camera and use that as a clipping stencil - can objects be parented to the camera?